# PYMC2 ZeroProbability error

Tags: python, pymc, log-likelihood

I have a model with 6 parameters with uniform priors:

```
parameter1 = pm.Uniform('parameter1',0.01,1)
parameter2 = pm.Uniform('parameter2',0,2)
parameter3 = pm.DiscreteUniform('parameter3',1,50)
parameter4 = pm.Uniform('parameter4',0,1.75)
parameter5 = pm.Uniform('parameter5', 0.005, 0.25)
parameter6 = pm.Uniform('parameter6', 0.005, 0.15)
```

I have a custom likelihood function that returns log likelihood value:

```
@pm.potential
def log_l(experiment=experiment,parameter1=parameter1,parameter2=parameter2,parameter3=parameter3,parameter4=parameter4,parameter5=parameter5,parameter6=parameter6):

    if parameter5<parameter4:
        return -np.inf

    parameters=[parameter1, parameter2, parameter3]

    log_l=calculate_probability(parameters, t_m, tol, n_integration, parameter4, parameter5, parameter6, experiment.decon_all[freq,:,:])

    return log_l
```

Where `calculate_probability` is a my function that returns log likelihood for this model given parameter values and observed data.
For some reason when MCMC samples:

```
model = pm.MCMC([parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,parameter5,parameter6,log_l])
model.sample(100)
```

and the programme satisfies the if condition (`parameter5<parameter4`) I get this error:

```
pymc.Node.ZeroProbability: Potential log_l forbids its parents' current values
```

I was wondering if anyone knows what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: The question here is: why are you using `pymc` instead of `pymc3`?

Comment: I tried using pymc3 first, but during sampling I need all parameter values to be floats or integers so that the calculate_probability function works, and I didn't know how to convert theano objects into floats. Are you suggesting that this type of model would be easier to handle in pymc3?

Comment: Yes, it should be easier in `pymc3`. Maybe this site can help you https://discourse.pymc.io/ with this: " and I didn't know how to convert theano objects into floats"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#the-potential-class):

> Potentials have one important attribute, `logp`, the log of their current
>     probability or probability density value given the values of their
>     parents. The only other additional attribute of interest is `parents`, a
>     dictionary containing the potential’s parents.

So the parents of your `log_l` are the arguments of `log_l`:

```
In [11]: list(log_l.parents.keys())
Out[11]: ['experiment', 'parameter2', 'parameter3', 'parameter1', 'parameter4', 
          'parameter6', 'parameter5']
```

Per [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/225958/842) (my emphasis):

> When a random variable is defined as a function of another random variable,
>     **PyMC checks that no value of the parent distribution leads to an impossible
>     value for the child distribution**.

Making `log_l` return `-np.inf` implies certain values of the parent variables are impossible. Hence, PyMC raises a `ZeroProbability` exception.

---

So instead of constraining the model by using

```
if parameter5<parameter4:
    return -np.inf
```

you could define `parameter5` with

```
parameter4 = pm.Uniform('parameter4', 0, 1.75)
parameter5 = pm.Uniform('parameter5', parameter4, 0.25)
```

to ensure that `parameter5 > parameter4`.

Comment: Great, thanks, this should work! I kept playing around with the code and put in a `if 4<5: return -np.inf` into the log_l function and it actually gives the same error. I was wondering if you would know why pymc is unhappy with the function returning `-np.inf`?

Comment: @Ale: returning `-np.inf` implies that certain values of the parent variables (namely `parameter4` and `parameter5`) are impossible (i.e., have zero probability). PyMC wants all values of the variables (defined by the domain of their distributions) to be *possible* even if improbable. If you want values to be impossible, they must be built into the definition of the distribution (e.g. `pm.Uniform('parameter5', 0.005, parameter4)`), not after the fact.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you for your help!